# WPF Fire event when DataGridCell is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am looking to fire an event when a cell in a WPF DataGrid is clicked, I have tried

XAML

```
   <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
         <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="b1SetColor"/>
      </Style>
   </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

C#

```
  void b1SetColor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Focused");
  }
```

But nothing happens (doesn't fire) when I do click the Combobox cell. is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use **`DataGridCellStyle`** and hook **`PreviewMouseDown`** event.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="b1SetColor"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: How do you do this without clobbering the rest of the (inherited) styles in the cell?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, you create one `Style` and use `BasedOn` to base another on it.

Answer (score 5):

On the level of `DataGrid` you can subscribe to `SelectedCellsChanged` event:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid SelectedCellsChanged="selectedCellsChanged"/>
```

C#:

```
void selectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
}
```

Comment: I believe this fires only when a cell is selected in a different *row*. If the user selects a different cell (i.e. different column) in the same row, this won't be hit. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It does fire even if the selected cell is in the same row as the previous selected cell.

Comment: NirmaIL is correct. Only fires if other row is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the grid

```
 SelectionUnit="Cell"
```

Then use the selectedCellsChanged solution provided by @PiotrWolkowski. Changing the SelectionUnit will make it fire even if it's the same row.

Answer (score 2):

- Ensure you are registered to: SelectedCellsChanged (and not to SelectionChanged)
- Set SelectionUnit="Cell"
- On your handler, get the cell selected and extract the Item bound:

  ```
        if (e.AddedCells.Count == 0)
        {
            lblSelectedItem.Content = "";
            return;
        }
        var cellAdded = e.AddedCells[0];
        var product = cellAdded.Item as Product;
  ```
- Then find the correct property by switching on DisplayIndex:

  ```
        if (cellAdded.Column.DisplayIndex == 0)
        {
            lblSelectedItem.Content = product.Id;
        }
        else
        {
            lblSelectedItem.Content = product.Name;
        }
  ```

I am also completely dissapointed by the ridiculous amount of complexity of wpf compared to winforms. why the hell the have not thought of a simple CellChanged event as it would be so trivial to handle...